# Should C# Asynchronous Library Methods Call await?

Tags: c#, async-await

Should an asynchronous library method call `await`?  For example, assume I have a data services library method that has access to an *Entity Framework 6* data context named 'repository'.  As far as I can see, I have two ways of defining this method:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<Blogs>>
    GetAllBlogsAsync(EfDataContext db)
{
    return await db.Blogs
        .OrderByDescending(b => b.Date)
        .SelectAsync();
}
```

or without `async`/`await` decoration

```
public static Task<IEnumerable<Blogs>>
    GetAllBlogsAsync(EfDataContext db)
{
    return db.Blogs
        .OrderByDescending(b => b.Date)
        .SelectAsync();
}
```

At the application end-point, in this case an MVC controller action,, the call would be the same for either method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Blogs()
{
    var blogs = await BlogService.GetAllBlogs(_blogRepository);
    return View(blogs);
}
```

This scenario could, of course, be more complicated where the application calls a chain of asynchronous methods.  Should each method in the chain call `await`, or should there only ever be one `await` statement at the end of the call chain, and what difference would this make?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean of call chain, I guess that depends how you define the methods. And the types will guide you to write correct code.

Comment: By 'call-chain' I simply meant that the application end-point might call an asynchronous method in a library that in turn called an asynchronous method in another library.  App calls Lib1.MethodX which calls Lib2.MethodY which calls Lib3.MethodZ and so on.

Comment: I honestly don't understand why you are asking this question. What do you think multiple `await`s would do?

Comment: I don't know, hence the question.  I suppose my concern is whether having an await method call another await method adds any overhead or indeed introduces the possibility of additional threading complications such as deadlocks.  The fact that I appear to be able to define the underlying library with and without with async/await bothers me as I do not understand what difference that might/might not make.

Comment: I believe your call should be BlogService.GetAllBlogsAsync in both cases.

Comment: Read [this blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx) by [Stephen Toub](https://github.com/stephentoub) and read it thoroughly. And while you're at it, take a look at [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) as well.

Comment: Thank you Nikola - the Stephen Toub blog is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should an asynchronous library method call await?

The short answer: Yes.

The long answer: Yes, unless you're concerned about memory churn on a server application *and* the method has nothing to do except call another method and `await`.

Removing the `async` and `await` is an optimization, but a very small one. And like most optimizations, it can cause problems unless you're very careful.

In your example:

```
return db.Blogs
    .OrderByDescending(b => b.Date)
    .SelectAsync();
```

This is roughly the same as:

```
var blogs = db.Blogs;
var query = blogs.OrderByDescending(b => b.Date);
var task = query.SelectAsync();
```

Only the last of which is an actual asynchronous call. In this case, it would be safe to elide the `async` and `await` only if you're positive `Blogs` and `OrderByDescending` will not throw exceptions.

Comment: if my data layer (EF) has `ToListAsyn()` am doing `await` on each layers `await db.ToListAsync().`  My business has something like this `await GetAsync()` and am using `await` at each layers. Is this correct way of doing this.

Comment: @Eldho: You should be using async "all the way", if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks , now im authentic about my usage of async

Comment: Having read arguments both for and against the use of await within library functions, I am somewhat torn as, for example, John Hanna's answer is probably the most technically pragmatic and correct.  However, on balance it seems that it is probably safer to use it than not  - particularly if you are not yet fully comfortable with these mechanisms and what they are really doing.

Answer (score 2):

You should be careful when passing a disposable object to an async method.

```
using (var db = new EfDataContext())
{
    return BlogService.GetAllBlogs(db);
}
```

If you dispose the DataContext before the Task executing the query completes, you may get a `ObjectDisposedException` (or any other type arised from accessing a disposed context).

If you can make sure that you are awaiting the task before disposing the context, it is better to simply return the Task (without async) since it will invlove one less step.

**Edit:**

While it is most common with disposable objects within a using block, the same goes for all types of references where you change the state of an object before the Task completes.

For example the following example will throw a `DivideByZeroException` once you call `await TestAsync();`

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public static async Task<int> DivideAsync(MyClass myClass)
{
    await Task.Yield();
    return 2 / myClass.Value;
}

public static Task<int> TestAsync()
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass { Value = 4 };
    Task<int> result = DivideAsync(myClass);
    myClass.Value = 0;
    return result;
}
```

So IMHO it's better practice to await the Task if you are ever changing the state of an object that the Task will use.

Comment: Good point, thank you.  Hopefully I will avoid this as I am newing up the repository with AutoFac dependency injection in the MBV controller's constructor using the InstancePerRequest() handler.

Answer (score 1):

If you return the internal `Task` you lose the ability to sanitise or handle exceptions that may have occurred in the internal method.

For instance, you may want to wrap all exceptions with a special type for your library:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<Blogs>>
    GetAllBlogsAsync(EfDataContext db)
{
    try
    {
        // If a fault occurs in the linq query, the 
        // exception is raised by the 'await' statement
        return await db.Blogs
            .OrderByDescending(b => b.Date)
            .SelectAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new BlogLibraryException("This blog appears to be broken.", ex);
    }
}
```

You cannot do this if you return the `Task` immediately as the initial exception won't be raised until the task is awaited.

As long as you avoid calling `Task.Wait`, `Task.GetResult` or `Task.Result` you won't be at risk of deadlocking. The overhead of spinning up a task is negligible, especially if you are simply delegating to a database for 'true async' (IO over a system boundary) work.

Comment: wait, isn't try-catch-throw an anti-pattern? why are you catching error you can't handle anyways?

Comment: Because someone outside using the library wants to handle BlogLibraryExceptions differently than any other Exception ocurring not caused by the library.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `async` there.

I would use it within a library though.

If you are tail-calling a method that returns a task, then not using `async` is:

1. Faster.
2. Simpler.
3. In-linable.
4. Just as easy to debug (are you really going to be confused by the fact that a stack trace doesn't come from an `await` point?)
5. Not likely to have an exception.
6. Not a big deal if the exception is thrown from the `SelectAsync` rather than the `GetAllBlogsAsync`
7. Trivial to replace with the `async` form if anything changes that makes it more desirable.

This last point is the more important. If it was some sort of big deal to make such a change then the premature pessimisation of `await` might be worth it in the name of caution, but it isn't.

The overheads of `async` are low, but why bother writing code just to introduce some overheads?

That does not mean I would answer "Should C# Asynchronous Library Methods Call await?" with a "no" though. In cases where the `async` is doing something other than tail-calling a task-returning method, I certainly would. I'd almost always do so with `.ConfigureAwait(false)` though, as I generally don't want context from the calling code being passed into the await I'm doing, and that could potentially cause deadlocks.